# Removing second last line from multiple text files

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple .TXT files where the second last line is a summary of observations (ie. (452,246) ).

While searching through the forum, I have come upon this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set file="test.txt"
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<%file%') do set skip=%%N
(
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" %file%^|findstr /v "^%skip%:"') do (
set "ln=%%L"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(!ln:*:=!
endlocal
)
)>%file%.new
move %file%.new %file% >nul
```

This code works perfectly on a single file, but I'm not sure how to alter this to run it against all files in my folder (*.txt).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code does not what you states, it removes the last line in the file, not the second last, if the result is what you need, ...

Enclose your code inside a new outer `for` loop that will iterate the list of files, and replace the reference to the file from `%file%` to the new `for` replaceable parameter

```dos
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

    for %%F in (*.txt) do for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^< "%%~fF"') do (
        (   for /f "delims=" %%L in (
                'findstr /n "^" "%%~fF" ^|findstr /r /v /b /c:"%%N:"'
            ) do (
                set "ln=%%L"
                setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
                echo(!ln:*:=!
                endlocal
            )
        ) > "%%~fF.new"
        move "%%~fF.new" "%%~fF"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. The FOR %%A loops through all text files in the folder you set as "dirpath".

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    Set "dirpath=PathtoYourFiles"
    FOR %%A IN ("%dirpath%\*.txt") DO (
    set file=%%A
    call :stripline
    )

:stripline
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<%file%') do set skip=%%N
    (
    for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" %file%^|findstr /v "^%skip%:"') do (
        set "ln=%%L"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!ln:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
    )>%file%.new
    move %file%.new %file% >nul
exit /b
```

Try that. If it doesn't work, use !marks on %file% like following:

```
    for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" !file!^|findstr /v "^%skip%:"') do (
```